# relational database design for a routing table

Tags: sql, networking, routes

I am trying to build relational database to store IPv4 routing table (unicast for now). Can anyone suggest how do I go about doing that following best practices?

Requirements: This database will store routing table for multiple routers/devices (1000+)

I am thinking this...

1. have a routers table that stores only routerid, hostname, etc.
2. have a interfaces table that stores only interface names (along with interfaceid) for each routerid
3. have a routingTable table that stores columns: IP prefix (subnet/route with mask); router (as routerid); outgoing interfaces as list of intefaceids (in case of load balancing)

My question is basically, how do I store the outgoing interfaces -  as a list or multiple tables?

Similar concept applies to multicast routing table too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i might have figured it out myself. I realized that storing the outgoing interface ids (aka OIL, outgoing interface List) in a list is not the best way, instead I would store the OIL in a table as oil_id, route_id, out_interface_id (which route_id, out_interface_id as unique) and assuming that out_interface_id is globally unique